# Take photo in python with 4:3 format instead of 16:9

Tags: python, module, camera, aspect-ratio, image-capture

I am going to use from raspberry pi camera with (camera.capture) command and take photo in 4:3 format instead of 16:9.
I will be appreciate that give me tips.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the image settings and camera effect like so :

```
camera.resolution = (2592, 1944)
camera.framerate = 15`
```

So if you set the resolution with

```
camera.resolution = (1280,960)
```

You'll have a 4:3 picture.

Comment: You're welcome, please mark my answer as valid